# how to set DISCOVERY_AS_LOCALHOST in Fabric -Gateway -Java? I set the environment variable, but it doesn't work

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

does anyone know how to set DISCOVERY_AS_LOCALHOST in Fabric -Gateway -Java?Gateway always resolvers the peer/orderer address to localhost. I set the environment variable, but it doesn't work.
Fabric and Gateway versions are 2.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the discovery as localhost to true if you are running the network locally

```
Gateway.Builder builder = Gateway.createBuilder();
    builder.identity(wallet, "appUser").networkConfig(networkConfigPath).discovery(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!Problem solved.It was my fault that the code static was set DISCOVERY_AS_LOCALHOST.So it's not in effect in the environment variable.